# Extensive search filtering and results->PDF in the front-end

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search, front-end, pdf

Is it possible to implement the following, and if so, what is the best (or one of) the ways to do so:

The setup:

- A custom post type 'listing'
- Custom taxonomies: 'artist', 'price', 'location', 'year', 'description' all displayed in the page
- With 1 or more images attached to the post

Is it possible to do the following **in the front-end**:

- A search/filtering system that uses checkboxes and allows me to do things such as:

  - Show posts by either 'Artist A' or 'Artist B', which were produced within years '1950-1960', while only in 'Country A'
- An option to create a PDF from those listings/search results with an option of two formats:

  - PDF format A: Basically uses the formatting in each post, with each post starting a new page as necessary (the rough equivalent of taking a screenshot of the page and throwing it in the PDF)
  - PDF format B: A table-formatted summarized list of the posts (using specific fields like 'thumbnail', 'title', 'artist', 'year')

For search/filtering system, I think [add_query_arg](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) would be what I can use but how do I implement it in a way that uses checkboxes?

For the front-end posts->PDF, I'm drawing a blank as I've never done anything like that yet.

The reason why I want to do it via front-end is because the two major users of this are not very familiar with technology in general so I'd like it to be as simple for them to use as possible.

Please assume that I am not that experienced with extensive modifications.

Answer (score 0):

`WP_Query` is your answer for the first question, you will need to create a custom search form, and parse that data, in order to create your custom `WP_Query`. Here is a [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/build-a-newspaper-theme-with-wp_query-and-the-960-css-framework--net-149) with a tutorial to get you in the right direction.

For the PDF part, I beleive it will be easier to tell the users to use Chrome and use the Print to PDF function, and create an stylesheet for printing that will adjust your site so it will hide what you don't want to show on the exported PDF.